# Purposes of testing

Tags: reference-request

At a conference, I heard a professor said that detecting error was only one aspect of testing (or purpose, I don't remember exactly). He said that testing is also used  to:

- Understanding the system
- Refactoring
- ...

I didn't have time to ask for references. I wonder if there are books or papers discussing about purposes of testing other than detecting errors. Note that I'm not asking for explanation, I'm looking for reference.

Comment: Which conference was it? Different communities may have a different outlook on testing. Are you specifically asking the point of view of computer scientists, as opposed to the point of view of engineers? You may get a different perspective on [sqa.se] or [softwareengineering.se].